# I'm getting error in particular line....what should I change?

Tags: java, sql, eclipse

This is the line where I'm getting the error

```
List<Map<String, Object>> users = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select * from user where email=? and pass=?",new Object[] { email, pass }, new MyRowMapper());
```

This is the whole code:

```
package com.example.dao;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.example.model.User;

@Repository
public class UserDao {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public int insert(User user) {
        return jdbcTemplate.update("insert into user values(?,?,?,?,?)",
                new Object[] { user.getName(), user.getEmail(), user.getPass(),user.getProfileimage(),user.getExpensetable() });
    }

    public int updateProfile(User user) {
        return jdbcTemplate.update("update user set name=?,pass=?,profile=?,expensetable=? where email=?",
                new Object[] { user.getName(), user.getPass(), user.getProfileimage(),user.getExpensetable(), user.getEmail() });
    }

    public User login(String email, String pass) {
        User user = null;
        List<Map<String, Object>> users = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select * from user where email=? and pass=?",new Object[] { email, pass }, new MyRowMapper());
        if (users.size() > 0) {
            user = (User) users.get(0);
        }
        return user;
    }

    private class MyRowMapper implements RowMapper<User> {

        @Override
        public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            User user = new User();
            user.setName(rs.getString(1));
            user.setEmail(rs.getString(2));
            user.setPass(rs.getString(3));
            user.setProfileimage(rs.getString(4));
            user.setExpensetable(rs.getString(5));
            return user;
        }

    }
}
```

This is the error:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/ExpenseSpringProject] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [select * from user where email=? and pass=?]; Invalid argument value: java.io.NotSerializableException; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument value: java.io.NotSerializableException] with root cause
>
> java.io.NotSerializableException: com.example.dao.UserDao$MyRowMapper

Comment: And what error are you getting? (Always, always, always tell us what the error is.)

Comment: *im getting error in line 31 what i should change* You should change your question and add the error message you get. What is the reason for answerers to manually parse your code to find an error?

Comment: already updated

Comment: The method with this signature is [deprecated](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-) in current version of Spring.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the wrong JdbcTemplate method.

The [method you are calling](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForList-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) takes a query and a varargs array of the bind parameter values.  The way you are calling it, you are passing the following as bind parameter values:

- an array containing your email and password.
- a row-mapper.

The row-mapper is not being used to map rows, instead you are attempting to pass it to the database as if it is a value itself.

I think you want to use [the overload of `JdbcTemplate.query` that takes a query, a row-mapper and the bind parameter values in that order](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-java.lang.Object...-).

Try replacing the line

```
    List<Map<String, Object>> users = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select * from user where email=? and pass=?",new Object[] { email, pass }, new MyRowMapper());
```

with

```
    List<User> users = jdbcTemplate.query("select * from user where email=? and pass=?", new MyRowMapper(), email, pass);
```

Once you've done that, the cast to `User` in the line `user = (User) users.get(0);` should become unnecessary and you can remove it.